# MYSQL & PHP - Return 1 result per IN variable, even if variables are not unique

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I am querying a database to return the `user_name` row, by `user_id`, with the following prepared statement in PHP:

`$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");`

If each of the variables in the `IN` statement are unique and in the database, I receive 1 `user_name` result for each variable. **However**, if the variables in my `IN` statement are not unique (2 of the user_id's are `foo`), I currently do not get a `user_name` result for each `IN` variable.

How do I modify my prepared statement, such that even if all of my variables in my `IN` statement were the same, I would still receive 1 row per variable, with `null` being returned if the variable isn't found.

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear, I found it difficult to articulate my problem here, please ask if anything is unclear and I will edit the question

Comment: if I understood correctly, you are querying a table with multiple `users` each with a unique user_id and you're passing `WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and expect the user with user_id=2 to be returned twice?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet yes that is correct

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in your application code

Comment: @Strawberry I'm not sure what you mean by that, could you please elaborate

Comment: Ok, that's not what `IN` is there for. The matching is done only once regardless of how many times a matching user_id is passed as argument. If you really need user_id 2 to be displayed twice, you should consider doing in the presentation layer or, if getting the data straight from the database is required, more complex queries like joining the table with itself may be required

Comment: "I'm not sure what you mean by that, could you please elaborate"  Most simple would be to create a display array something like `$array[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  and create a records array in which you store your data from the database.. And just simple loop and match the display array with the records array and echo them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `left join` instead:

```
SELECT u.user_name
FROM (SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT ? as user_id
     ) uu LEFT JOIN
     users u
     USING (user_id);
```

A `WHERE` clause only filters out rows.  It does not multiply them.  But a join does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm new to SQL so just wrapping my head around it now

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`? a `INNER JOIN` is needed here

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think LEFT is correct. With INNER, it won't show null for user_name if any of the user_id's aren't matched. It just won't return those rows at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And impressively fast response

Comment: @Don'tPanic your right i read over the part where the topicstarter also asked for non matches.. Then the qeury should be indeed a `LEFT JOIN`